# Let $a >0$. Find the area bounded by $x+y=a$ and $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{a}$.

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $a >0$. Find the area bounded by $x+y=a$ and $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{a}$.

Graphing this it's a line $x+y=a$ on top of the curve $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{a}$. So solving for $y$ in both equations I have that $y= a-x$ and $y= (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})^2$

So the integral becomes $$\int _0^a\int _{\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}\right)^2}^{a-x}1 \ dy \ dx = \int _0^a\left(-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{x}-2x\right) \ dx = -\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{a}a^{\frac{3}{2}}-a^2$$

but this seems to have a negative area, what might be happening here?

Comment: The minus inside the square before the integral magically became a plus in the bounds.

Comment: lower bound $(\sqrt a + \sqrt x)^2$ is incorrect.

Comment: If you fix that, you get $a^2 / 3$

Answer (score 3):

Note that the area is
$$\int _0^a\int _{\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x}\right)^2}^{a-x}1 \ dy dx = 2\int _0^a\left(\sqrt{ax}-x\right)dx =\frac{a^2}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

The method shown here is overkill, but I thought it would still be interesting to demonstrate. One could also consider changing coordinates from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ with

$$\begin{cases}u=\sqrt x\\v=\sqrt y\end{cases}$$

Then $x+y=a$ transforms to the circle $u^2+y^2=a$ of radius $\sqrt a$ centered at the origin, while $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=a$ transforms to the line $u+v=a$ that passes through $(0,\sqrt a)$ and $(\sqrt a,0)$. The area element would be

$$\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}u_x&u_y\\v_x&v_y\end{bmatrix}\right|\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv=4uv\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$$

The bounded region in the $u$-$v$ plane is the segment of the circle in the first quadrant. To see this, pick any point in the original bounded region and see which point it maps to in the $u$-$v$ plane. (Plots shown below use $a=1$ and the point $(x,y)=\left(\frac13,\frac13\right)$, which maps to $(u,v)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)$.)

[image]

Denote by $R$ the original bounded region, and by $S$ the transformed region in $(u,v)$ coordinates. Then the area of $R$ is

$$\iint_R\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\iint_S4uv\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv=4\int_0^{\sqrt a}\int_{\sqrt a-u}^{\sqrt{a-u^2}}uv\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du=\frac{a^2}3$$

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did was graph the two equations.  Of course x+ y= a is the straight line through (a, 0) and (0, a).  $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}= \sqrt{a}$ is more "interesting".  When x= 0 we have $\sqrt{y}= \sqrt{a}$ so $y= a$.  When y= 0 we have $\sqrt{x}= \sqrt{a}$ so $x= a$.  This graph also passes through (a, 0) and (0, a).  In the "middle", with x= y, $\sqrt{x}+ \sqrt{y}= \sqrt{x}+ \sqrt{x}= 2\sqrt{x}= \sqrt{a}$ so 4x= a.  x= a/4.  (a/4, a/4) is a point on the graph so the graph of $\sqrt{x}+ \sqrt{y}= \sqrt{a}$ lies below the graph of $x+ y= a$.  Of course, from $x+ y= a$, y= a- x and from $\sqrt{x}+ \sqrt{y}= \sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{y}= \sqrt{a}- \sqrt{x}$ so $y= (\sqrt{a}- \sqrt{x})^2= a- 2\sqrt{ax}+ x$.

We want to integrate $y_1- y_2= a- x- (a- 2\sqrt{ax}+ x)= 2\sqrt{ax}- 2x$ from x= 0 to x= a:
$\int_0^a 2a^{1/2}x^{1/2}- 2x dx$

Comment: FYI, $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}= \sqrt{a}$ is the first quadrant portion of the parabola with vertex $(\frac{1}{4}a,\;\frac{1}{4}a)$ and axis of symmetry $y=x$ that opens "upward" in the north-east direction (i.e. in the "origin to $(1,1)$" direction). This can be seen by rationalizing and then rotating by $45$ degrees to get $x = \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4a}\right)(2y^2 + a^2)$ (assuming I haven't made an error somewhere).